# C++ Primer exercise 2.27 [5th ed.]

Tags: c++, reference, declaration, qualifiers

I am doing exercise 2.27 from C++ primer 5th edition and I am confused in this question:

**Exercise:** Which of the following initializations are legal? Explain why.

**(c) const int i = -1, &r = 0;**

I came to conclusion that r is illegal because this will be same as below:

```
const int i = -1;
int &r = 0;
```

But [this github repo](https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer/tree/master/ch02#exercise-227) suggest that (c) is same as below:

```
const int i = -1;
const int &r = 0;
```

So, it contradicts to my answer, please provide me the correct answer.

P.S.: I am begineer in C++ language.

Comment: _" I am begineer in C++ language."_ Then Stack Overflow is probably the wrong place for you.

Comment: What makes you think that answer might be wrong? This question comes across as simply you choosing to disregard that answer, because accepting it would mean you were wrong.

Comment: You can check whether the compiler agrees with you by using `std::is_same` and `decltype`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0bb0ba07726c1e6

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Beginners can certainly ask beginner questions here. It's just that they have to be *good* beginner questions, by the same standards of *good* as get applied to the rest of us.

Comment: Just like the type `int`, the qualifier `const` is for all variabled defined in the same declaration statement.

Comment: @hvd You're right, but such cases are rare from my experience.

Comment: @milleniumbug , thank you!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , understood.

Comment: A tip for beginners (and everyone else) is to avoid declarations like `const int i = -1, &r = 0;`. Just declare each variable on a separate line, and you don't have to wonder what it means.

Comment: @BoPersson , yes , syntax can be quite confusing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type specifier (`int`) with the qualifier (`const`) belong to all declarators in the declaration

```
const int i = -1, &r = 0;
```

Thus declarators `i` and `&r` have the type specifier and qualifier `const int`. 
Moreover you may not write for example

```
int &r = 0;
```

because a temporary object (in this case expression 0) may not be bound to a non-constant reference.

However you could write

```
int &&r = 0;
```

Comment: does this also apply to `volatile` qualifier?

Comment: @silverwolf This is applied to cv qualifiers.